# Sending data to aws using api

Tags: php, python, api

I need to send an image to aws using an API in PHP. The image comes from the webcam, I have set up the aws as well, the backend neural network on aws is in python. I need to directly take the image I get from the webcam and send it to the backend and the neural network should start processing the image. How do I write an API call to the backend? And how do I start the backend code in one swift flow, without having to run the backend separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in aws beckend which  aws you are using please speify your so other can understand and suggest you path as per it.

you can do one thing upload image to s3 and trigger lambda if image uploaded to s3 using lambda you can trigger other services. if you are using lambda as beckend service then it will easy

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

.

Comment: This site is not a coding service